# How to create vertex transition from one mesh to another using shapekeys

Tags: python, vertices, shape-keys

I have two objects imported from photogramometry scans. They have at most few milions of vertices and are triangulated. I would like to produce a mesh with added shapekey which could show morph from one object to the other one. The number of vertices is not the same and two meshes are in fact independent.

Question: how to create a new object, which will have a shapekey added which show the fluent shortest-path morph between two original objects?

My partial solution: I tried to create shapekey with vertices positions set to start and end as from two meshes. But the problem is that even this simplest approach does not work. And the problem remains bigger because there could be different number of vertices. I think I could create the shift of smaller mesh from it's position to the bigger one, but the questions arise how to select vertices for a shapekey and how?

This is a very simple test which do not work. Any ideas how to solve this in a whole or some partial hints?

```
import bpy
ob1 = bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices
ob2 = bpy.data.meshes['Cube.001'].vertices
V = [[],[],[],[]]

print("V:")
for i in range(0,len(ob2)):
#    print(ob1[i].co)
#    print(ob2[i].co)
    dx = ob1[i].co[0] - ob2[i].co[0]
    dy = ob1[i].co[1] - ob2[i].co[1]
    dz = ob1[i].co[2] - ob2[i].co[2]
    V[i] = [dx,dy,dz]
    print(str(V[i]))

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].shape_key_add('Basis')
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].shape_key_add('Trans')

k = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key'].key_blocks['Trans'].data
for i in range(0,len(k)):
    k[i].co[0] = ob1[i].co[0] - ob2[i].co[0]
    k[i].co[1] = ob1[i].co[1] - ob2[i].co[1]
    k[i].co[2] = ob1[i].co[2] - ob2[i].co[2]
```

Comment: Do you need to use python? I would make the shapekey by hand using [snap to face](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#snap-element)

Comment: For simple shapes I can do this by hand, but shapes I have often have hundreds of thousands of vertices at least and are complicated. Using snap to face do not work for them I afraid. For such a task python seems to be the most precise tool.